# Delphi XE format json string

Tags: json, delphi

I need to prepare JSON and send it to a website. I am using `TJSONObject`. My code is simple:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  JsonArray,JsonArray1:TJSONArray;
  F,F1:TJSONObject;
begin
  FJSONObject.AddPair('api_password','password');
  FJSONObject.AddPair('method','POST');

  F:=TJSONObject.Create;
  F.AddPair('nest1','v1');
  F.AddPair('nest2','v2');
  JsonArray:=TJSONArray.Create;
  JsonArray.AddElement(F);
  FJSONObject.AddPair('Main array',JsonArray);
end;
```

As a result I've got this JSON:

```json
{
  "api_password": "password",
  "method": "POST",
  "Main array": [
    {
      "nest1": "v1",
      "nest2": "v2"
    }
  ]
}
```

But, according to the website`s API, I need to send this JSON instead:

```json
{
  "api_password": "password",
  "method": "POST",
  "Main array": [
    {
      \"nest1\": \"v1\",
      \"nest2\": \"v2\"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I make this JSON?

Comment: `TJSONObject.ToString` automatically adds escape characters where needed. I don't have a deep knowledge about that but I think that your site's API doesn't expect a standard JSON string

Comment: Guy from website sad that array of second level in json structure has to be protected by “\” in other case can`t parser json string

Comment: @DmytroLendel I think you are either misreading the API doc, or the doc is wrong. If the website admins say the doc is not wrong, and the example shown is what they are really expecting, then the website has a faulty JSON parser, because the example is not legal per the [JSON spec](http://json.org). Strings cannot have their opening/closing `"` characters escaped as shown. Only `"` characters *inside* of strings can be escaped.

Comment: Is their API doc public? If so, why did you not include it?

Comment: yes. it`s public but not in English https://glaz.systems/api-emulator#

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ it`s json validator

Comment: @DmytroLendel that is what online translators are good for. But what you linked to is not an API doc, it is an API emulator, and you didn't specify which specific command(s) you are trying to implement in your code. But if you are trying to tell people to use a JSON validator, then the site is not going to use illegal JSON, like you claim. So I still think you are misunderstanding what the API actually wants.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding an object to `JsonArray` you need to add a string. At that point, when generating a string from `FJSONObject`, it will automatically replace all `"` with `\"`. However, this will only work if `F` does not contain any `"`, otherwise `F.ToString` must be replaced with `F.ToString.Replace ('\"', '"' )`. You also need to handle `F` lifetime, because it is no longer handled by `FJSONObject`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  JsonArray : TJSONArray;
  F : TJSONObject;
begin
  FJSONObject.AddPair('api_password', 'password');
  FJSONObject.AddPair('method', 'POST');
  F := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    F.AddPair('nest1', 'v1');
    F.AddPair('nest2', 'v2');
    JsonArray := TJSONArray.Create;
    JsonArray.Add(F.ToString);
    FJSONObject.AddPair('Main array', JsonArray);
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Unfortunately what you want is not a standard JSON format and you can't easily generate it. If you add a string to `FJSONObject`, it will be automatically treated with `"`. Same for all elements of the array, if you add the array directly. So there's always something to be replaced manually and when generating the result, you also need to use this line.

```
FJSONObject.ToString.Replace('["{', '[{').Replace('}"]', '}]')
```

Comment: As shown, `TJSONArray.Add(F.ToString)` will produce `["{\"nest1\":\"v1\",\"nest2\":\"v2\"}"]` instead of `[{\"nest1\":\"v1\",\"nest2\":\"v2\"}]` like the OP is asking for. The `"` characters between the `[{` and `}]` sequences would have to be stripped off manually.

Comment: ToString does not add \" :-(

Comment: Solution is JsonArray.Add(ReplaceStr( F.ToString,'"','\"')); I checked result and seems it`s ok

Comment: @Dmytro Lendel I don't think, that could work, it will just create `\\"` from `\"`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I missed that, I've already updated the answer.